# Pandas python merge columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

i`m trying to merge a column from another .xlsx file to another file.

This is the column(repoPath) that i want to add from another file:
[image: repoPath from another file]

And this is the file where i want to add it:

[image: Where to add "column C"]

And this is my script:

```
from svnscripts.timestampdirectory import  createdir,path_dir
import os
import time

def gitrepolastchangedate():
    pathdest=path_dir()
    dest=createdir()
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    #below you read the file from the declared path

    ###processing FOR "TCDD"
    df = pd.read_csv(rf"{pathdest}\{timestr}-rawGitData-reposLastChangeDate-tcdd.csv", sep='|', header=None)
    dfGitReposSize=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,"GitReposSize.xlsx"))
    df.columns = ['repoPath']
    df[['repoPath', 'repoLastChangeDate']] = df["repoPath"].str.split(";", 1, expand=True)
    df["repoLastChangeDate"] = df["repoLastChangeDate"].str.strip("-")
    df.to_excel(os.path.join(dest, "GitRepoLastChangeDate.xlsx"), index=False)
    Result = pd.merge(
        df,
        dfGitReposSize[
            [
                'repoPath',


            ]
        ],
        left_on='repoPath',
        right_on='repoPath'
    )
    Result.fillna("N/A", inplace=True)
    print(Result)
    #Result.to_excel(os.path.join(dest, "GitRepoLastChangeDate.xlsx"), index=False)
gitrepolastchangedate()
```

The idea is that im trying to add the 'repoPath' from the other file comparing the keys, but idea is that the keys isn`t exactly the same. Because on file that i want to add the keys contains in the begining that : /srv/git +key

So what im thinking its the right key should contains a str{/srv/git} +key or idk..

The output that i receive is:
Its not even creating the 3rd column...

[image: output]

Example for both file.xlsx:

file1:

```
repoName             repoSize        repoPath
./m4r_media-sync.git    812K    tcdd/m4r_media-sync.git
./m4r_isd-software.git  538M    tcdd/m4r_isd-software.git
./ext_oam-updater.git   2.5M    tcdd/ext_oam-updater.git
./build.git 9.8M    tcdd/build.git
./m4r_isd-adminapp.git  3.5M    tcdd/m4r_isd-adminapp.git
./m4r_moving-map.git    4.5M    tcdd/m4r_moving-map.git
./m4r_inet-portal.git   332K    tcdd/m4r_inet-portal.git
```

FILE WHERE TO ADD:

```
repoPath    repoLastChangeDate
/srv/git/tcdd/build.git 05/23/2022
/srv/git/tcdd/ext_apache2.2-fix.git 10/18/2016
/srv/git/tcdd/ext_oam-updater.git   05/19/2022
/srv/git/tcdd/m4r_cctv-trx.git  07/28/2017
/srv/git/tcdd/m4r_ffmpeg-tcdd.git   08/04/2016
/srv/git/tcdd/m4r_fleetstat.git 09/11/2020
```

so the column "repoPath" from file 1 needs to be add on file 2 on column C having the name (repoName)  for the coresponding row of this file

Comment: can you share minimal reproducible example with say few data for both the dataframes

Comment: i added at the end of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see all your  rows for `repoPath` in the first dataframe contains prefix `/srv/git`. We can merge both the dataframe on `repoPath` excluding the prefix `/srv/git/`

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(r"GitReposSize.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel(r"GitRepoLastChangeDate.xlsx")
df1['newrepoPath'] = df1['repoPath'].map('/srv/git/{}'.format)
df1 = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on='newrepoPath',right_on='repoPath', how='left').drop(['newrepoPath'], axis=1)
```

##### Saving as excel

```
df1.to_excel(r'FinalResult.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: thanks, accepted because map solution is much faster than strsplit

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
["./m4r_media-sync.git",    "812K",    "tcdd/m4r_media-sync.git"],
["./m4r_isd-software.git",  "538M" ,   "tcdd/m4r_isd-software.git"],
["./ext_oam-updater.git",   "2.5M"  ,  "tcdd/ext_oam-updater.git"],
["./build.git", "9.8M"    "tcdd/build.git"],
["./m4r_isd-adminapp.git",  "3.5M"   , "tcdd/m4r_isd-adminapp.git"],
["./m4r_moving-map.git",    "4.5M"    ,"tcdd/m4r_moving-map.git"],
["./m4r_inet-portal.git",   "332K"  ,  "tcdd/m4r_inet-portal.git"],
    
], columns=["repoName" ,   "repoSize" ,   "repoPath"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([

["/srv/git/tcdd/build.git", "05/23/2022"],
["/srv/git/tcdd/ext_apache2.2-fix.git", "10/18/2016"],
["/srv/git/tcdd/ext_oam-updater.git", "  05/19/2022"],
["/srv/git/tcdd/m4r_cctv-trx.git", " 07/28/2017"],
["/srv/git/tcdd/m4r_ffmpeg-tcdd.git", "  08/04/2016"],
["/srv/git/tcdd/m4r_fleetstat.git", "09/11/2020"]

], columns=["repoPath"   , "repoLastChangeDate"])
```

Create a new column for merge

```
df2["repoName"] = str("./") + df2.repoPath.str.split("/").str[-1]
```

Merge both dataframes based on repoName

```
result_df = df1.merge(df2, on=["repoName"], how="inner")
```

Rename columns

```
result_df.rename({"repoPath_y" : "repoPath", "repoPath_x": "repoName"}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Extract output:

```
print(result_df[["repoPath", "repoName", "repoLastChangeDate"]])
```

Sample output:

```
    repoPath    repoName    repoName    repoLastChangeDate
0   /srv/git/tcdd/ext_oam-updater.git   ./ext_oam-updater.git   tcdd/ext_oam-updater.git    05/19/2022
1   /srv/git/tcdd/build.git ./build.git None    05/23/2022
```

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/3jGPWNj)  this is the exepected output , the column need to pe added as column3 in the df2

Comment: i assumed that the repopath will match across excel and used inner join. if needed change it to left/right based on the input.